# django graphene how to get a list of fields from the model.py

Tags: python, django-models

I'm using graphql together with django. My model.py might look like:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)        
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    field_c = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How can I get a list of all fields in a different class (i.e. schema.py)?

```
from .models import MyModel

model_fields = MyModel.__dict__
```

does not give me a list of fields.
Thanks for a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

```py
model_fields = MyModel._meta.fields
```

Long answer:

You probably want to use in graphene's built in functionality if you want to handle different models without explicitly writing the fields out. You can use the [graphene_django](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/) library to do this

So lets say you have this in models.py:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field_a = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    field_b = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

then in schema.py you probably want to do this:

```py
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from .models import ModelA, ModelB


class ModelAType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA

class ModelBType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
```

These will create a graphene object with your model fields copied over for you. You can even add other fields on:

```py
class ModelBType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelB

    model_a = graphene.Field(ModelA)
    
    def resolve_model_a(self, info)
        return ModelA.objects.filter(field_a=self.field_b)
```